# How to find the reason for not started services

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-28

I am a WildFly rookie and I have the problem that when WildFly is packaged (Maven) and the bootable.jar file is started, then the logs say the following:

> WildFly Full 28.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 20.0.2.Final) started in
> 41627ms - Started 2270 of 2397 services (248 services are lazy,
> passive or on-demand)

When I search for errors, there are none, but it seems odd to me that services are lazy/passive/on-demand and not started.

Is that an issue I should be worried about?

If yes, how can I resolve this problem?

And is there a way to identify the lazy/passive/on-demand services?

I simply don't know what to try because I don't know where to start. Looking up this problem gives no clue about how to resolve it in general.